# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError: /home/thibaut/fastmeet/src/components/Header.js: Adjacent

Tags: reactjs, module, babeljs, loader

I need help. I don't find the response to resolve this problem on StackOverflow so I post my question.
I got this error:
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/thibaut/fastmeet/src/components/Header.js: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (18:7)

I am trying to put Login in Header.js

Header.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Header.css'
import { Navbar, NavDropdown, Nav, OverlayTrigger, Tooltip, NavbarBrand } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Events from "react-bootstrap/Button";
// import Login from "react-bootstrap/Button";
// import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';


class Header extends Component{


  render (){

    return (
      
          <h1>La boîte à recettes de </h1>
       <div className>
         <Login/>

       </div>
    );

  }
}



export default Header;
```

App.js

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header';


// import Login from './components/Login'

class App extends Component {
//   state = {
//     pseudo: this.props.match.params.pseudo
//   }


render () {
    return (
      <div className="box">
        

      <Header></Header>
      
    
       
     
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

React JSX accepts only one child component in the return statement. So you can enclose multiple HTML tags inside one div tag or use react fragments

Like

```
<React.Fragment>   
   <h1>La boîte à recettes de </h1>
   <div className>
     <Login/>
   </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

or better use <></> instead of <React.Fragment>

Answer (score 0):

React JSX accepts only one div component in the return statement. so enclose your JSX in header.jsx with a div like below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Header.css'
import { Navbar, NavDropdown, Nav, OverlayTrigger, Tooltip, NavbarBrand } from 
'react-bootstrap';
import Events from "react-bootstrap/Button";
// import Login from "react-bootstrap/Button";
// import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';


class Header extends Component{
  render (){
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>La boîte à recettes de </h1>
          <div className><Login/></div>
      </div>
    );
   }
}
export default Header;
```